# streamlit with tab1 and multiSelect/Radio

Tags: python, asynchronous, dashboard, streamlit

I am trying to have a multiSelect and/or in a streamlit tab. everytime I update one of those, the whole thing reruns and I don' get anything

I first tried this

```
with tab1:
                        with st.form("Select Mode:"):
                            selectOrAll = st.radip_button("Submit")
                            iio("Select or All", ["Select", "All"], key="SelectOrAll")
                            submit = st.form_submit:
                                st.write(selectOrAll)
                        if selectOrAll == "All":
                            if appCache.renderedFigures["distribution"]["All Distributions"] is not None:
                                st.plotly_chart(appCache.renderedFigures["distribution"]["All Distributions"])
                        if selectOrAll == "Select":
                            if appCache.renderedFigures["distribution"]["Selected Distributions"] is not None:
                                keys = list(appCache.renderedFigures["distribution"]["Selected Distributions"].keys())
                                selectedDistributions = st.multiselect("Select Distributions to display", keys, key="selectedDistributions")
                                if selectedDistributions:
                                    for distribution in selectedDistributions:
                                        st.plotly_chart(appCache.renderedFigures["distribution"]["Selected Distributions"][distribution])
```

And then wanted to use a simpler version but even that didn't help that much

```
with tab1:
                        if appCache.renderedFigures["distribution"]["Selected Distributions"] is not None:
                            keys = list(appCache.renderedFigures["distribution"]["Selected Distributions"].keys())
                            selectedDistributions = st.multiselect("Select Distributions to display", keys, key="selectedDistributions")
                            if selectedDistributions:
                                for distribution in selectedDistributions:
                                    st.plotly_chart(appCache.renderedFigures["distribution"]["Selected Distributions"][distribution])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Streamlit's execution model reruns the entire app whenever a user interacts with a widget. Can you share a runnable code snippet so we can reproduce the issue?